# Python request module getting first response after reqeust.get api call

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am making an GET call through requests in Python 3.7.  This GET request will trigger a job. Once the job gets triggered on the host side it has set of attributes such as run id and other parameters.  The host has an idle timeout of like 120 seconds and the job that was triggered will run more than 120 seconds.  Since the get request is blocked until a response is thrown, in this case it times out after 120 seconds we are getting expected 504 error.  But if the job completes within 120 seconds, the get request header response has details of run id and other attributes.

What I am trying to accomplish is the moment request.get is submitted, is there a way to get immediate response back with run id and other details.  I can use that run id to poll the the host to get back the response code even after 120 seconds through a separate API call.   I tried to search the blog but was unsuccessful.  If request module cannot help in this case, please advice if other modules will come handy for my need.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: import json
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
url='https://<url with job name>'
response = requests.get(url, headers = {'Authorization': 'Token'})
print(response.headers)
print(response)

Comment: So, from what I could understand, you want the job to be started, and a response with the job ID, when the GET request from the client is made. So, on the server, why don't you use a thread? That is, run the job in a thread, update some common variable (with the Job ID) inside the thread, and then send this back, as the response of the GET request.